# Thinking in C++(vol 1) Ch-12 Q-21

Tags: c++, c++11

Got stuck here while going through Bruce Eckel TIC++

**Create a class with an assignment operator that has a
second argument, a string that has a default value that
says “op= call.” Create a function that assigns an object
of your class to another one and show that your
assignment operator is called correctly.**

Is this really possible. Does C++ allow **operator=()** to have multiple argument?? I tried this:

```
class X
{
public:
    X& operator=(const X& x, string val = "op=call")  //! error
    {
        // ...
    }
};

int main()
{
    X x1;
    X x2;
    x2 = x1;
}
```

Error given by compiler:

```
[Error] 'X& X::operator=(const X&, std::string)' must take exactly one argument
```

I think this is not a valid question or if it is then how to provide multiple argument to assignment operator??

Comment: That doesn't look legal to me. And what's the point of `val`? Why would checking for equality require a third argument? And how would that argument even be given, unless it entirely relies on default behavior?

Comment: [I would find a different book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Correct. There's no point in adding third argument. Even if we try so, compiler comes up with strict error.. **Exactly one arg**

Comment: The operator should be a free function, not a member of the class

Comment: @balki `operator=` can't be a free function. It must be implemented as a member function, taking exactly one argument.

Comment: @NathanOliver Correct idea, but bad link: it's recommending exactly this book in 5th place!

Comment: @NathanOliver I have edited said link and removed this book to the "classics/older" section ...

Answer (score 1):

The most recent edition of *Thinking in C++, Vol 1* was published in 2001.  New C++ Standards have been published three times since then (2003, 2011 and 2014).

My guess is that Eckel is demonstrating a loophole in the Standard, which was later corrected. (Or possibly, since this loophole I'm presupposing would be such an edge case, your compiler may have merely implemented the intended behavior accidentally, instead of a strictly following the Standard)

Comment: Even C++98 specified that a copy assignment operator (or any overloaded assignment operator) have exactly one parameter.  I suspect that your last sentence is correct - the book's example was relying an accident of some early compiler(s).

Comment: Even VC++6 wil not compile the assignment operator with a second parameter.